# insert xml form into a splist as a multi-line text data type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, xml

am forming a xml format in the UI created in my form in SP2013.
I am creating a xml file having elements and nodes, now I need to  insert this dynamically  generated xml file into a multi-line text column in my splist,
 how to achieve this.
As far  as I know, SPList doesn't have a xml column data type.

Comment: Does it matter? As long as you have selected plain text it should be fine.

Comment: but , I am unable to insert into that list column . also I need to retrieve as well.

Comment: Edit your question with your code.

Comment: its higH time MSFT would start create a datatype "XML" in SPLIST and SP DOC LIB.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that it a multiple line text column of type `Enhanced rich text` as below:

[image]

I created a column using this and was able to add `xml` data as below. Below is screenshot of the item display form:

[image]